# How can I set the value of an editable text field (annotation) in a pdf?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, pdfkit, ios-pdfkit

In my app users will enter information on one screen that gets put into a database. On another screen I want to display a pdf with their information used to fill out the edit text fields (annotations). In the example below the user can click "John Smith" currently and type a new name.

[image]

Using ios PDFKit I am able to display the pdf and allow the user to edit. I am unable to update text in the text boxes or change the status of checkboxes. It looks as though I do have read/write privileges for the pdf.

With my current code I was able to get the number of pages of my pdf and print off the annotation names of every annotation so I can get the names of the fields I want to set values for but the setvalue function does not work and checking the contents of a filled textbox shows nil.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    displayPDF()
    updatePDFText()
}

func displayPDF() {
    let pdfView = PDFView()

    pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(pdfView)

    pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: MY_PDF, withExtension: "pdf") else { return }

    if let document = PDFDocument(url: path) {
        pdfView.document = document
    }
}

func updatePDFText() {

    guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: MY_PDF, withExtension: "pdf") else { return }

    if let document = PDFDocument(url: path) {
        for index in 0..<document.pageCount {
            if let page = document.page(at: index) {
                let annotations = page.annotations
                for annotation in annotations {
                    //print("Annotation Name :: \(annotation.fieldName ?? "")")
                    if annotation.fieldName == "SSN1" {
                        annotation.setValue("TEST", forAnnotationKey: .widgetValue)
                        page.removeAnnotation(annotation)
                        page.addAnnotation(annotation)
                    } else if annotation.fieldName == "District" {
                        annotation.buttonWidgetState = .onState
                        page.removeAnnotation(annotation)
                        page.addAnnotation(annotation)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an issue with my implementation or is there another method of programmatically updating the pdf annotations?

Comment: You'll want to save the updated pdf

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue Chris? I’m currently researching how to do this